# How to save values to PIC18?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I would like to store some values to my PIC18 then retain those values even if the power is lost or the unit is reset. An example of the values I would like to save would some something like those 4 digits, 0100.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update**: Would this be the way to go?

```
    unsigned char value;
    unsigned char DEEdata = 0x25;
    unsigned int  DEEaddr = 0x04;

    DataEEInit();
    dataEEFlags.val = 0;

    DataEEWrite(DEEdata,DEEaddr);
    value = DataEERead(DEEaddr);
    Nop();
```

Answer (score 2):

In mikroc_for_PIC IDE simply you can use :

EEPROM_write(_Addres,char);
char = EEPROM_Read(_Addres);

note that: after write it is best if you have delay about 20 ms.

Comment: That's nice, unfortunately I use MPLAB C18 compiler.

Comment: I think it usually take < 3mS to write EE but you are right about the delay. I normally wait 5mS to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

EEPROM in PIC micro-controllers can save data for long period of time. PIC16F84 can store 64 bytes. It is not that much, but it can serve your purpose. A good description to how to write to and read from EEPROM in PIC16 is given in this link.

http://www.romux.com/tutorials/pic-tutorial/eeprom-data-memory

Comment: Please check my update. I provided a sample code but I am not sure if this is how you would do it.

Comment: It should work. Anyways, if you plan to work in Assembly, datasheet is the way to go. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39564c.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you use `HIGH-TECH` as compiler you can simply write and read from `EEPROM` (which is the only way for keep a value after power lost except FARM ICs) with below function:

```
Write_b_eep
Read_b_eep
```

you can find these function from below directory if you install `HIGH-TECH`:

```
...\HI-TECH Software\PICC-18\9.80\sources\plib\EEP
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few milli-seconds for the data to write into EE.
If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM it explains the 
electrical and physical process of both erasing and writing and gives a time between 0.1 and 5mS to achieve this.
Write or find a micro-second delay routine (hint the timers are good for this)
Change your code to

```
unsigned char value;
unsigned char DEEdata = 0x25;
unsigned int  DEEaddr = 0x04;

DataEEInit();
dataEEFlags.val = 0;

DataEEWrite(DEEdata,DEEaddr);
wait_us(5000); // Wait 5mS.... data takes a while to burn into EE
value = DataEERead(DEEaddr); // now its available to read
```

The EEPROM write function, is a bit `fire and forget'. You command it to write
and it gets on with it in the background. If you read too quickly after writing you are not guaranteed the value you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

When using MPLab IDE v6, the functions to be used are generated by MCC using the memory peripheral.

The read/write can be achieved like this:

```
uint16_t EEPROM_address = 0x00; // address in EEPROM space
// Writting to EEPROM
DATAEE_WriteByte(EEPROM_address, (uint8_t) 42 );
// Reading from EEPROM
uint8_t stored_EEPROM = DATAEE_ReadByte(EEPROM_address_N0);
```